# Layout suggestion for transimpedance amplifier guard

Tags: operational-amplifier, layout, transimpedance

I want to know what is best way to layout a transimpedance amplifier circuit like below. We have amultiplexer that picks the gain resistor  and a feedback capacitor. (I am  not worried about VGND position and also resistor values just for demonstrations.) I know you have to keep the feedback resistor and capacitor close to opamp but in this case I can not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMuOWe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. Should anything change in the layout below? Should I connect the feedback resistors in one side or both sides? (Yellow line, loop to reduce trace length.)

[image]

Also if you have suggestion on layout or circuit to reduce noise effect since the sensor produced very little current (10nA-100uA.)

2. I want to know should I cover sensor+ trace  surrounding with via to GND or VGND (I think it should be GND) and where should I put the guard?